# Magento Collection GroupBy getSize

Tags: magento, collections, count, group-by

I have a collection:

```
$this->_totalVersions = Mage::getModel('downloads/files')
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_groups', array('like' => '%'.$customergroupId.'%'))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', 1)
                                ->getSize()
```

Works perfectly! but when I add a `group` it doesn't work.

```
$this->_totalVersions = Mage::getModel('downloads/files')
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_groups', array('like' => '%'.$customergroupId.'%'))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', 1)
                                ->getSelect()->group(array('main_table.name'))
                                ->getSize()
```

I dont want to use `->count()`  or `count($collection)`
because it holds 90.000+ items.

Is there a proper way to count the collection?

Thanks in advance,

Martijn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, thanks Guerra for your reply. You pointed me into the right direction.

I just solved it after a couple of hours.. the trick was to add a filter into the resource collection `XXXXX_Downloads_Model_Mysql4_Files_Collection`

```
public function addGroupByNameFilter()
{
    $this->getSelect()->group('main_table.name');
    return $this;
}
```

Applying this filter:

```
$this->_totalItems = Mage::getModel('downloads/files')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_groups', array('like' => '%'.$customergroupId.'%'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', 1)
        ->addGroupByNameFilter()
        ->getSize()
```

works like a charm! That way I will keep my `XXXXXXX_Downloads_Model_Mysql4_Files_Collection` object. : )

Cheers,

Martijn

Comment: great! adding params `groupBy($field, $table = null)` makes it perfect then

Answer (score 2):

The method "getSize()" is implemented on Varien_Data_Collection, when you call "getSelect()" in your collection it return a "Zend_Db_Select" object and this one doesn't implement getSize method.

So you can use the way that magento implements the getSize on collection but in your Zend_Db_Select., you can't group on collection just in Zend_Db_select.

Magento do like this:

```
 $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

// Count doesn't work with group by columns keep the group by 
if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    $countSelect->distinct(true);
    $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
} else {
    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
```

Understand?

Magento reset all "heavy" arguments of the query, and simply make a query just with "COUNT(*)", but if you need to use group just COUNT(*) will count your groups, so you emulate group result with DISTINCT.